# Why Doing Check Permission by email address shows 2 users

Tags: permissions, user-profile

I have a strange scenario.

When we doing Check Permission in SharePoint (2010) using email address it shows 2 users. The 2 users displayed have different email addresses.

[image]

Why it could be so.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just matching the string with what you typed in box and Display Name of the users and gives the best possible results

Comment: Hi SharePointGoa, Thank you for the reply. To just elaborate about issue. on AD out of 22 users listed above 1 exists. Now, when user logs in he is shown his name (display name) of the other account. I have ran a full user profile sync but still the other user exists. And am afraid of manually deleting the other account as it may cause permanent access block of user

Comment: Any comments...